# POST X-www-form-urlencoded array of objects with PostMan?

Tags: postman

I want to send an array of objects.

```
[{"error":"kaboom1","accident":"explosion1"},
{"error":"kaboom2","accident":"explosion2"}]
```

I am able to successfully send the data using raw json format, but i am required to send the data as x-www-form-urlencoded.

I've been trying different permutations but i am unsuccessful.

i.e. `alert[0][]` , `alert[].[]` etc.

What do i set the key and value to achieve this output?

```
%5B%7B%22error%22%3A%22kaboom1%22%2C%22accident%22%3A%22explosion1%22%7D%2C%0A%7B%22error%22%3A%22kaboom2%22%2C%22accident%22%3A%22explosion2%22%7D%5D
```

[image]

Comment: dont use [] brackets. use the key as alert and value as the json

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `[]` in the keys. Postman will convert non-unique keys in x-www-form-urlencoded into an array in the request body